# Proper indexing for an InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-optimization

I have an InnoDB table with the following columns

- id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
- a VARBINARY(16)
- b CHAR(2)
- c VARCHAR(100)
- d MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED
- e TINYINT UNSIGNED, range 0-49

I'll be performing such a query most of the time

```
SELECT d, e, c FROM tbl WHERE a=0x5caffbb2 AND d>1000000 AND (e=1 OR e=5 OR e=6 OR e=8 OR e=15)
```

How should I set up indexes for

1. maximum SELECT speed
2. decent SELECT speed and high INSERT speed

Comment: How often are you inserting records?

Comment: very often, sometimes up to 1000x, usually like 50 per second

Comment: The fields you are selecting based on are all ints. So probably worth a covering index on those. Probably worth avoiding indexes on the varchar / char fields. Note that your primary key has a max value of 16777215, which with 50 records inserted per second will over flow in ~93 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieve maximum *select speed* via composites or covered indexes. Problem is, your varchars will get in the way. They (at least one at the moment) are too wide for covered, but your ints are not. So consider choosing a composite index in the most frequently used fashion such as

```
key (i1,i2,i2)
```

for some ints.

For maximum insert speed, choose `LOAD DATA INFILE`, the hands down fastest approach, even in cases of interactive GUI apps. It takes some configuration of worktables to bring in data. You will need to juggle concepts such as whether or not the data previously existed. And often craft special `update with a join` pattern solutions for getting the data into the real table from the work table. The fact of the matter is that no looping with binding will achieve this throughput.

Answer (score 1):

**For the select:**

```
INDEX(a, d)
```

First column(s), namely `a`, in index should be compared "= constant".

Then comes one range, namely `d > ...`.

The other stuff is hard to index because of `OR`.  However, it is all the same variable: `e=1 OR e=5 OR e=6 OR e=8 OR e=15`, which is equivalent to `e IN (1, 5, 6, 8, 15)`.  So, this is better:

```
INDEX(a, e, d)
```

This is because the optimizer (in 5.6) can "leapfrog" through the index for `e`.  That is, after all the '=' columns, and before the one 'range', you have one 'IN'.

This is a "covering" index:

```
INDEX(a, e, d, c)
```

It *may* be even better.  There is a tradeoff between the bulkiness and the "covering".  It is not easy to predict whether it will be better; furthermore it may be better for some values and worse for others.  This will be 320 bytes versus 20.

(Note: the columns in this index, and the others, *must* be in the order given.)

[*more*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/compound-composite-indexes/).

**For the `INSERT`**

`LOAD DATA` is probably the best.  However if the number of rows in the `LOAD` are too many, it may have an adverse impact on the `SELECTs`.  Also very good is batched `INSERTs` of 100-1000 rows per batch.

**VARBINARY**

That is probably a packed MD5 or IPv6?  It may as well be `BINARY(16)`?  It does not hurt the indexing as much as some people say.

**InnoDB**

Of course, use InnoDB, not MyISAM.

Comment: thanks for explanation and yes the VARBINARY is IPv6